# Smooth scrolling on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, scroll, smoothing

I used this code:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

and the smooth scroll work perfectly between a link and an anchor!

But how can I make following button code work for ?

```
<input type="button" value="btn">
```

Comment: On clicking on this button, how do you wish to target any specific element then? Using value attribute or what? Or, do you wish this button to be the target? Or do you wish to trigger anchor click event? Etc... Your question is quite unclear imho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
$('input[type="button"][value="btn"]').on('click',function (e) {
```

If you need both separate them by a coma:

```
$('a[href^="#"], input[type="button"][value="btn"]').on('click',function (e) {
```

---

But I would strongly recommend to use a common class for them and access like this:

```
$('.common_class').on('click',function (e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click',function (e) {
```

instead of:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The old style could work too:

```
<input type="button" value="btn" onclick="$('a[href^=\"#\"]').trigger('click')">
```

But you should avoid that style (inline event)